# How to insert JSON string format into velo (WIX) textbox

Tags: javascript, json, dropdown, velo

I'm trying to show this JSON in textbox when the user selects 'CHART JSON' option in the dropdown

```
var data_chart = {"data":{"labels":["_2024_03_09","_2024_03_10","_2024_03_11","_2024_03_12","_2024_03_13","_2024_03_14","_2024_03_15"],"datasets":[{"label":"10JiFG1L7Y","type":"line","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,802],"backgroundColor":"rgba(173,118,240,0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(173,118,240,1)","borderWidth":1},{"label":14029,"type":"line","data":[0,22,0,0,16,0,36],"backgroundColor":"rgba(29,22,1,0.2)","borderColor":"rgba(29,22,1,1)","borderWidth":1}]},"customization":{"borderWidth":1}}
```

To do so I used `JSON.stringify(data_chart)` to feed the dropdown with the "CHART JSON" value

```
 $w("#dropdown2").options  = [
        { label: "SQL", value: "No Code" },
        { label: "CHART JSON", value: JSON.stringify(data_chart)}
        
    ];
```

and insert it into the textBox:

```
export function dropdown2_change(event) {
    // Set the value of textBox1
    $w("#textBox1").value = $w("#dropdown2").value
}
```

But it shows item2 instead of the JSON, if I change it to string for example 'chart' it shows chart (as expected), how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Apparently its not allowing it in and thus defaulting to "Item 2" since its 2nd. Possibly because the value contains special chars that seem too hackery for WIX to allow in. ... With that said, there are far more effective ways to get the json into the textbox than assigning it to the value attribute of the option.

Comment: What are the others ways to get the JSON into textbox? what the alternative?

Comment: I'd need more information about your codebase. What is this "dropdown"? Is that using a select tag beneath the hood?

Comment: The user can select 'SQL' or 'Chart' from the dropdown, if the user select 'Chart' I want to show him the chart JSON and allow him to edit it. https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/dropdown/value

Comment: Ok. Having just checked your wix link, the dropdown supports events. You'll want to look into the `onChange()` method. In your callback (event handler), change the text box to whatever value based on the selected option. https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/dropdown/onchange